# Display content to diverses type of role but not all

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to display content to a certains kind of user (some of them custom) if they are logged-in.
Is there a way to associate :

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && ($user_role != "Administrator" && $user_role != "customrole") ):

// display content
       
 else:

// redirect back to other page
wp_redirect( 'https://customurl.com' ); 
    exit;

endif;
```

But when I try thsio code I have a fatal error. What do I do wrong please ?
Best regards,
Clément

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna use multiple conditions you have to remove the () afther your && in the if statement and try it like this

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && $user_role != "Administrator" && $user_role != "customrole"){
//display content
}
else{
wp_redirect( 'https://customurl.com' ); 
exit;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to remove the restriction induce by "if user logged in" on certains pages or posts ? Meaning on most of the post I want that restiction to be alive and on specific one I want to remove it. I've set up the restriction on the php template of a custom post type.

Comment: I will look at it in a few hours. I will change this comment to a possible answer if your problem haven’t been solved :-) sorry for the late reaction i had a break :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was a mix, I used permission and a custom field if I want some part accessible to everyone :

```
$access_to_everyone = get_field('access_to_everyone');
// var_dump($access_to_everyone);
if ( $access_to_everyone == true ) {
    $access = "granted";
} else {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if ( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
            $access = "refused";
            }  
        } else {
            $access = "granted";
        }
    } else {
        $access = "refused";
    }
}
if ( $access == "granted" ) {
    display A;
} else {
    redirection";
}
```